# How to read an int array and check its x and y size

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file that the 2 first numbers are the line and column count of an array. Then it may or may not have the correct size array in the following 'line' lines. That's what I need to do, read line by line of this array (in this file) and check if the line and column size match the ones passed at the beginning of the file.

I tried using `fgetc` but if you have a number with more than 2 digits (like 10) it will treat as 1 and 0, not 10. I couldn't figure out how to use `fscanf` since when it reaches an end-of-line it simply goes to the next line, so I can't keep count of the array lines.

Example using `fgetc`:

```
char t;
while(1) {
    //pega um char
    t = fgetc(file);

if(t == ' ') {
    continue;
} else if(t == '\n') {
    //verifica se o num de colunas lido é igual ao passado no inicio do arquivo, se for incrementa a linha e zera as colunas
    if(j == y) {
        i++;
        j = 0;
        continue;
    } else {
        //se nao for igual, sai do programa
        return -1;
    }
} else if(t == '0' || t == '1' || t == '6' || t == '7') {

} else if(t == '2') {
    coordIni++;
} else if(t == '3') {
    obj1++;
} else if(t == '4') {
    obj2++;
} else if(t == '5') {
    obj3++;
} else if(t == '8') {
    item1++;
} else if(t == '9') {
    item2++;
} else {
    //usou algo maior q 9 ou menor q 0
    return -1;
}

mapa[i][j] = t - '0';
j++;
```

}

But as I said, in this case if the file has eg 10, it will read 1 then 0, and that can't happen.
How can I solve that?

Ex. input:

Correct one:

5 5

1 1 1 1 1

1 2 1 5 1

1 0 1 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 1 1

Incorrect:

7 7

1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 0 2 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Just a heads-up, the newline between each line of the array is not present on the file, I don't know how to post array here, it was showing in a single line all the array here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample text file? How is it delimited? You could use `strtok` and `fgets` to delimit base on characters (space, comma, etc) and newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `scanf` work in this situation: all you need to do is to scan the next character after the float, like this:

```
int val;
char ch;
int count;
while ((count=scanf("%d%c", &val, &ch)) != EOF) {
    printf("%d - %d\n", val, (count == 1 || ch == '\n'));
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/R1Y6Dr)

The program above reads `int`s from the standard input (use `fscanf` to read from a file). The character which follows `int` is stored in `ch`. You can compare that character to `\n` to see if you got the end-of-line or not. Note that if the last line does not have `'\n'` you would read one, not two, inputs. You can detect that you've reached the end of the last line by checking the number of items.

Another alternative would be computing the length of the longest valid line based on the number of columns that you expect, allocate a buffer of that size, and read the file line-by-line using `fgets`. You could then parse each individual line with `sscanf`, `strtok_r`, or `strtol`.

Comment: The snippet above works except for the last item on the array, since the scanf will not return 2, because it will read the %d but not the %c. since there is no newline after the last item. How can I solve that ? Check this: http://ideone.com/UmqcX0

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Please see the update. I also changed the demo to match the new code.

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari You are welcome! Note that this approach is not 100% bulletproof - one could full it by placing spaces between numbers and end-of-line characters. However, in most practical situations this approach would be good enough.

Comment: It's a college work, the entries will be kinda standard, so I shouldn't worry about that. Thanks again !